# CSS selector for a single attribute out of multiple attributes

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

how do you select a single attribute within the element

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" title="xyz" alt="xyz">
```

just need the img src

seems to be an overlooked question
as all assumed implementations yield the entire tag still

Comment: Can you please provide us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Some html code and your python code. So we will be able to help you.

Comment: `img::attr(src)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your element is actually something like

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" title="xyz" alt="xyz">yo!</img>
```

the xpath expression

```
//img/@src
```

Should get you `xyz.jpg`.

Comment: Not to pick cherries, but what is the css selector for this? img[src] still returns the element and all attributes within in scrapy.

Comment: @Xquared - This is using xpath, not a css selector. `src` is an attribute of the tag `<img>`, and the value of this attribute is selected by specifying `@attribute_name` (or `@src`, in this case) in the path.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for the css selector... my previous comment???

Comment: @Xquared - Sorry, your question was tagged both xpath and css, so I thought you want one or the other. But try `img.attrib['src'] ` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I just mentioned, 'not to pick cherries' as in not to be overly specific. Thanks for helping me. The xpath worked, I just also wanted the css selector as well since it isn't working in any of the implementations I've seen given. For styling yes, but scraping or at least 'Scrapy' framework, no. The entire element is scraped.

Comment: You can't select attributes with css selectors, you would only select elements.